# Rewrite vanilla JS forEach into jQuery Each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I am trying to keep my code consistent as I'm using jQuery for my project, however, I'm a bit confused about the `each()` method of jQuery.

`let cells=$(".cell").toArray();`

my Vanilla JS code is here:

```
cells.forEach(function(cell,index){
    cell.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log(cell,index);
    })
})
```

my jQuery is here:

```
cells.each(function(index,cell){
    cell.click(function(){
        console.log(cell,index);
    })
})
```

I know the code is wrong, as the console shows `Uncaught TypeError: cells.each is not a function` but I checked the jQuery Document, it says the `each` method is the `forEach` method in JS, I am really confused now.

Comment: you can just do `$(".cell").click(function(){})` no need to use `.each()` or `$(cell).click(function(){})`

Comment: jQuery doesn't extend JS `Array` type, so change your `cells` defining just to: `let cells=$(".cell")`. Now you can use `cells.each(...)`

Comment: `$(".cell")` will give you a jquery object/collection.  `.toArray()` will convert that to an array.  There's no `.each` function on a js array (it's `.forEach`).  So your issue is simply the `.toArray()` which converts it so it's no longer a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".cell").each` is a function. `$(".cell").ToArray().each` is not a function.

jQuery's `each` method exists on a jQuery object, not on vanilla JS arrays.

Comment: There are 2 "each" methods in Jquery.  See:  https://api.jquery.com/each/ and https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/.  One is for a DOM object and the other method is more generic, which might be what you are thinking of.